# How to display User Events from Google Calendar on Android Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-calendar-api

I want to show my client Google Account Calendar Events on Android Screen, I'm having my Client's google Account email and Password.

Answer (score 2):

if you have credential than follow this step

1) Login into this https://www.google.com/calendar/render

2) Make calendar public so you can get events via feed. follow instruction from this https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083?hl=en

3) How to get XML feed for calendar event?

ans : In the calendar list on the left, click the down-arrow next to the calendar you want to embed, and select Calendar settings. (Alternatively, click the Settings link at the bottom of the calendar list, then click the name of the calendar.)  than click on xml button. see below image

[image]

so you will have feed link and you can parse them into your app.

Enjoy :)

Comment: I have created the XML URL like you said ,how to parse the XML and display the Events in Android Could you help?

Comment: can you share your XML link?

Comment: follow this tutorial for xml parsing  http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sjm6mdaoghv5kipc2p80jrgsc0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic

Comment: Please check this,i want to display the Event Time on Android Screen

Comment: check resource and there you have tag like title,when etc. parse out them. and search on google for xml parsing